# Angular.js app - api secruity

Tags: api, security, angularjs

We are currently making and angular based app. All info comes from an api.

We don't want to store any state on the client side with cookies etc. So when a user refreshes the app, we had planned to call `/account/details` which will return the user object if logged in, false not.

The trouble is, the security model we have used is that we set an `auth-token` (returned as part of the user object from the above `/account/details` or successful `/login` call) that is sent in the header of any api request.

The api checks that this `auth-token` sent in the header matches what's in the `logged-in-users` table and sends back the data if there is a match.

Obviously, the problem is, on refresh we aren't saving anything client side so don't have this `auth-token` to send any more.

The api, as it's on the same domain sets a php session cookie. We were thinking that for this `account/details` call **only** we could match the session cookie value against the `logged-in-users` table. However this sounds dodgy to us. Would this be ok? Or is there another much simpler way to overcome this chicken and egg situation?

Comment: You say in the second paragraph that “we don't want to store any state on the client side with cookies,” but in the last paragraph you state that “the API […] sets a PHP session cookie.” Are you or aren't you okay with using cookies?

Comment: We ideally don't want the front end to set any cookies. If it is the best way to go then we can use JS to set the an auth-token cookie. Is there a better way though?

Comment: Is there any reason you're rolling your own authentication token in a new header rather than just using the PHP session or having the API set a cookie?

Comment: The only reason is that eventually the API may not run on the same domain in which case it won't be able to set cookies. Right? Talking about it out loud now, I think the only way is to store the auth-token in a cookie. We were originally following this method http://www.jamesward.com/2013/05/13/securing-single-page-apps-and-rest-services but have lost our way a bit. :)

Comment: If the API doesn't run on the same domain, it won't be able to set cookies accessible to your application, but it should be able to set cookies that it itself can access. I do now see that you're trying to protect against CSRF attacks, which does indeed make things trickier…

Comment: Maybe i'm saying wrong but ... Your server side has to be stateless ... so the token's lifetime is just the session's time ... So a cookie in the header is a good thing. Make an httpInterceptor to listen the response and get the status code 401,403, ... At the end of the session the cookie is over and well done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider having the application use `sessionStorage` to store the authentication token. This has the advantages of the cookie you're looking for, but is maintained by JavaScript and is not automatically sent to the server.

Comment: That actually could be a good solution. Will give that a shot. Thankyou.